# Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib when loading Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

When I try to load the remix ide on browser

I'm getting the following on the console of the browser

```
Loading https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/soljson-v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.js without worker
soljson-v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.js:3 Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib
```

It is warning as indicated by the yellow
[image: Invalid member error on Remix IDE]
After loading the contract from private network, I am able to get a particular function however unable to set value using Metamask.io Chrome extension. It is giving me error - invalid sender.
Are these 2 errors related in any fashion?